# Filter using WHERE but not GROUP BY

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am pretty new to SQL, so it might be obvious but I am stuck. I have a table where I am counting song plays based on a few conditions. My problem is that one of the columns (songlength) I want to filter on but I dont want to group by it in the output because it will give the wrong output.

Here is my pseudo code:

```
SELECT COUNT(songid) AS Plays, songlength, artist
FROM MyTable
WHERE artist = Justin AND songlength > 10000
GROUP BY artist
HAVING Plays > 0
ORDER BY Plays DESC
```

How would I achieve this best?

Comment: You have to remove it from the output then.

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, _except those who are arguments to set functions_.

Comment: Exactly as @Crick3t said... You usually don't need to SELECT the column even if you're filtering over it. The other option would be to create a nested query where you make the filtering in the inner most query and the evaluation/grouping/counting in the outermost one.

Comment: Post some sample input and the expected output.

Comment: I think the main question is what is wrong in the output when you add it to group by?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try writing this way. When you put some non aggregated field in select list then it is mandatory to put same columns in group by. The solution you are looking, below code can help. Try and let me know

```
SELECT COUNT(songid) AS Plays, artist
FROM MyTable
WHERE artist = 'Justin' AND songlength > 10000
GROUP BY artist
HAVING Plays > 0
ORDER BY Plays DESC
```